# I'm overwhelmed with authenticating users for my first simple web app. I'm using JSF2.0 + Tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, authentication

I realize there are a myriad of questions concerning authentication.  All of them overwhelm me at the moment.  They seem to be overkill for what I want to do.

I'm using JSF 2.0 with Tomcat.

I want to create a sort of "Hello World" app that allows log in/authentication.  I want the user to be able to log in and submit some text via a simple form.  Subsequent log ins will simply display the most recent text they submitted and allow for additional text submissions.

The eventual site won't be this trivial, or course, but I want to lay the log in/authentication groundwork as this looks like it'll be my the biggest hurdle for me.

As a first maybe hacky run I created my own rudimentary authentication.  Which will  get to my essential question...  Why is what I've done wrong/insecure?

Upon registration I store the user Id and password in the data base.  I will be using some sort of hashing algorithm to store the password, but I haven't decided what to use yet.
Upon log in, I look for a match of the user Id/password submitted from the client.  If there's a match, I store the userId in a managed bean of session scope and the user is on their way to accessing their data (just a String for the time being).

Doing it this way seems too easy to me based on all of the sophisticate stuff I've been reading.  Why is my method bad?  I also need to learn how to use HTTPS for the log in/registration forms, correct?

I know I haven't given you much to work with.  Sorry for the poorly formulated question.  I'm struggling to get a foothold on this subject and which direction to go for a solution that isn't massive overkill.  i.e. I don't want to use Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a big answer. But in short you need to do the following:

First, For a basic form based authentication take a look at this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncby/index.html)

but you need to have some way of retrieving the role in web.xml from LDAP directory or a database or some other service.

So you need to configure a realm to access the role from a database(in your case) which is mentioned [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html)

and finally if you want to use SSL you need to configure this mentioned [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Another example [link](http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2011/09/tomcat-using-realm-to-protect-access-to.html). If you still need some clarity grab a copy of Core JavaServer Faces book and refer to 12 chapter.